# TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable is shown when using while loop

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to use two while loops with variables a,b. but typeerror is shown. not sure why it is showing this error. Shouldn't i be able to do this?

```
a,b=0

while a<2:
    a=a+1
    while b<3:
        b=b+1
```

Comment: Should be `a = b = 0` or `a, b = 0, 0`.  Your current code is trying to unpack an integer `0` into two elements which is not possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As previously mentioned, the error can be fixed with either a=b=0 or a,b=0,0
The number of values to be referenced to has to be equal to the number of variables when using the (x,y=a,b) format. But it's more convenient to use the a = b = 0 method when you're trying to give multiple variables just one value.

Comment: Thanks. your answer helped

Answer (score 0):

this seems to work. A simple change.

```
a=0

while a<2:
    a=a+1
    b=0
    while b<3:
        b=b+1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = 0;b = 0    
while a<2:
    a=a+1
    while b<3:
        b=b+1
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.